# Ruby Key Using Split and Join

Tags: ruby

I have a written exam here, here's the instruction.

> Write a program that prints out groups of words that are anagrams. 
>   Anagrams are words that have the same exact letters in them but in  a
>   different order. Your output should look something like this:

```
["demo", "dome", "mode"]
["neon", "none"]
```

(etc)

And here's the solution for this:

```
words =  ['demo', 'none', 'tied', 'evil', 'dome', 'mode', 'live',
          'fowl', 'veil', 'wolf', 'diet', 'vile', 'edit', 'tide',
          'flow', 'neon']


result = {}

words.each do |word|
  key = word.split('').sort.join
  if result.has_key?(key)
    result[key].push(word)
  else
    result[key] = [word]
  end
end

result.each do |k, v|
  puts "------"
  p v
end
```

I've been trying to understand the ruby code solution but can't easily grasp it. One of my question is how can you test the `result` hash if it has no key or any element contain from it. Another thing how does the .`join` and .`sort` works on this code.

I am really confuse how it all go thru the answer. Can somebody out there can explain on this codes line by line in a layman's term a beginner who is a dummy like me can understand?

Comment: Adding to the good explanation by @GaganGami : Even if you would not use `has_key?`, the expression `result[key]` is valid, if the key does not exist. It would, by default, simply return `nil` for a missing key. However, a different default value can be requested, when the Hash is constructed.

Comment: If you found any of the answers helpful please select the one you liked best.

Answer (score 7):

I would just do this:

```
words =  ['demo', 'none', 'tied', 'evil', 'dome', 'mode', 'live',
      'fowl', 'veil', 'wolf', 'diet', 'vile', 'edit', 'tide',
      'flow', 'neon']

words.group_by { |word| word.chars.sort }.values

#=> [["demo","dome","mode"],["none","neon"],["tied","diet","edit","tide"],["evil","live","veil","vile"],["fowl","wolf","flow"]]
```

Comment: [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html) really does make this sort of thing super easy.

Comment: Can you explain your solution line by line in laymans term a dummy like me would understand?

Comment: @tadman, it only makes it look easy. There are efficiency issues to address for larger sets.

Comment: @tadman it isn't inefficient. Suppose the words are all `m` letters long, this algorithm is O(n * m * log(m)) where n is the size of the array. Do you have a faster solution?

Comment: @MikkPoles it's a one-liner ;-)

Comment: @Aetherus I think this solution is acceptably fast and I'm not sure what Boris has in the way of concerns. The question wasn't about processing billions of megabyte long strings.

Answer (score 2):

I will explain the code for you.

```
key = word.split('').sort.join
```

This will create array of characters from string, sort the letters alphabetically and then join the characters into new string. This way, key for the hash is created.

For example word "mode" will be transformed to array `['m', 'o', 'd', 'e']`, than sorted `['d', 'e', 'm', 'o']` so the final key string will be "demo". This way words "mode" and "demo" will have the same key in the hash.

```
if result.has_key?(key)
  result[key].push(word)
else
  result[key] = [word]
end
```

If branch of the condition checks if hash has the given key and if it does it adds the word to the array. Otherwise it will assign array with just the word to the key.

Comment: Here `result = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [ ] }` would save a lot of conditional work. Then you can just `result[key] << word`